# VMWare/VirtualBox hangs Ubuntu while installing Windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, virtualbox, vmware

I am trying to install Windows 7 in VMwarePlayer or VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04LTS and every time I have tried it the result is that Ubuntu hangs and only hard reset works. 
I tried both VMware and VirtualBox softwares and different WIndows 7 iso images.

My Ubuntu never hangs - NEVER. Only with this virtualization stuff...

What could it be?

Cheers,
Marteau

Comment: I have just tried with Windows 8.1 and it is the same - Ubuntu freezes and no other possibility than hard reset... Any ideas? Do you know where can I find the logs from the crash?

Comment: And the same happened when I tried to install Mint... So it looks that there is something wrong with the laptop settings? Or hardware? Or with what?

Comment: Did you try enabling virtualization in your BIOS?

Comment: Thanks, Jobin. I haven't tried this, but it was the setting of the VirtualBox... I will look and see if I can enable virtualization. I have old Toshiba Satellite PRO U200...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out at least on Virtualbox. I changed the chipset settings and as well deactivated Extended Feature: PAE/NX. And I have Windows 7 as guest OS...

I will try later on to do the same on VMwarePlayer if I find the settings ;)

Regards,
Marteau